# Unable to add layer to GeoServer - Origin does not correspond to request

Tags: geoserver, http

I am unable to add a layer to GeoServer, whenever I click to add layer and select a store from dropdown, I get

```
HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.
Reason: Origin does not correspond to request
```

I have tried setting **GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST** to allow-list of proxy with the CSRF filter but no luck, even tried setting GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED property to true but that also didn't work. Recently we shifted out GeoServer from http to https

Can someone tell me how to resolve this or possibly the reason for it to occur

[image]

Comment: What OS is Geoserver deployed on.  Did you use a web archive, binary, or a Windows Installer.  Are you using Tomcat, Jetty, or something else?  This person had an issue with their web.xml.  https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9353?inbox=true&=   This stack overflow answer has a link for how to configure geoserver for HTTPS.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094508/how-can-you-load-maps-from-geoserver-using-https   Lastly, Stack Overflow might be more appropriate for this issue.

Comment: This is almost certainly a [CSRF problem](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html) - please use the [edit] link to provide details on how you set the CSRF parameters

Answer (score 6):

Similar problems with Geoserver 2.20.4 deployed under tomcat 9 with apache proxying from https://example.com/geoserver/ to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ on Debian 11. Could access the geoserver web admin interface but certain pages, such as the "security" tab on an "edit workspace" page, would fail with the "Origin does not correspond to request" error.

1. Found that setting GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLE to true in /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml works. Not sure what the security implications of that might be. I have a firewall running with port 8080 blocked so I think that should be fine, but I wanted to get the WHITELIST working instead.
2. Finally, found that reverting GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLE to false and adding the following WHITELIST in /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml works:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST</param-name>
  <param-value>example.com,example.com:8080</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Geoserver CSRF documentation is [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html), as other answers and comments have noted.

Comment: it works (tested 2nd option)

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly GeoServer checks both the Origin-header and the referer-header when posting forms. Depending on how you have set up https it might be the culprit. I had a similar problem when we used IIS as a proxy to serve GeoServer as https. The referer-header then contained "https" in the adress, but Geoserver was hosted in jetty using http and then expected the referer-header to contain "http". As we also had a reverse proxy in front of the IIS, I just modified the referer-header to contain http:// instead of https:// and GeoServer was happy.

But I think that Geoserver has a configuration to ignore the referer header, but I can't find it now.

**Edit**: the configuraion is GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST or GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED, which is set in web.xml or as a system property or as an environment variable. See https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html for complete documentation.

**Edit 2** Just realized Ian hade provided that link in a comment...

Comment: Could it (also) be related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)?

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to configure these variables using docker-compose configuration, include the following entries in environment:

```
  geoserver:
    image: docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.x
    environment:
      GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLE: "false"
      GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST: 'example.com,example.com:8080'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And don't forget to configure **Global** > **Proxy Base URL** (https://example.com/geoserver), and check **[x] Use headers for Proxy URL** in Geoserver Configurations